# PHP XDebug in distributed environment (cloud)

Tags: php, azure, cloud, xdebug, azure-storage

As far as I know, PHP profiling tool XDebug saves its results into files. However, it's difficult to deal with such files when the application runs in the cloud distributed environment. What's the best practice to manage such situation? Is there any way in XDebug (preferably somewhere you can place custom handler/callback) you can use to save the results into shared storage?

(Disclaimer: My app runs on MS Azure platform)

Comment: It might be possible to use your local machine for debugging using the remote settings of XDebug http://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Comment: One approach would be to use Windows Azure Diagnostics to copy XDebug output files to Blob Storage (you can configure Diagnostics to copy any file(s) to Azure storage). This post talks about PHPUnit test results, but the concepts might be useful to you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/01/03/automating-phpunit-tests-in-windows-azure.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible, you can use the **xdebug.profiler_output_dir** together with [DirectoryConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.diagnostics.diagnosticmonitorconfiguration.directories.aspx) in Azure Diagnostics. The DirectoryConfiguration will pick up the contents of a LocalResource and save it to blob storage.

This is what you'll need to do:

1. Create a startup task that updates the xdebug.ini with the path to the local resource (you can start [here](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/using-a-local-storage-resource-from-a-startup-task) if you plan to do this with a script)
2. Configure the DiagosticsManager to use that directory and ship it to your blob storage. Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.diagnostics.diagnosticmonitorconfiguration.directories.aspx) example.

Once you've done this you can access your results using any storage client (like Cloud Storage Studio, CloudXplorer, ...).